# Android, actual hour issue

Tags: java, android

I use the following code to get hour in Android devices, and works well.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

But I have a 4.1.2 device that don´t work, because the hour given is not in 24 hours mode. For example, if actual hour is 18:32, return 6:32. The time of this device is properly set from the device settings menu. Moreover I have on and off the network time, from settings menu, and the result is the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`AM_PM`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#AM_PM) field in the `Calendar` instance. It will return either AM or PM, based on which you could add 12 hours to it or take it as such.

To maintain compatibility with other devices, it's better to use `HOUR` (instead of `HOUR_OF_DAY`) in conjunction with `AM_PM`.